# Why doesn't Django Rest Framework APIRequestFactory support query_params for DELETE method?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-delete

In one of my view, I'm passing additional data as query params in APIView delete method. I'm able to fetch the same using the `request.query_params` in the view. But when I'm trying to test the same with DRF APIRequestFactory, the data is empty. Digging further through the APIRequestFactory code shows me that its only looking at `request.data` and not on `QUERY_STRING`. Is there any specific reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Im curious about that too...

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue on github and it has not solved yet.
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6488